# How to import iPhone videos into Instagram without distortion?

Tags: iphone, video, instagram

Whenever I take a video with the standard camera app and then import it into Instagram on my iPhone 5S, the video ends up distorted.

A still from the original video:

[image: Video]

A screengrab showing distortion:

[image: Distorted video]

I suspect this occurs due to the different aspect ratios of the two formats.

Is there any way to either:

1. Take video in the default camera app in Instagram's 1:1 ratio, or
2. Crop video in the Instagram app so that it doesn't distort

Comment: The Instagram app records video in square format, however - at least that works. What happens when you record video in landscape view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Instagram doesn't allow video cropping at the moment. Nor can you change the Camera app's aspect ratio. I suggest either recording inside Instagram or changing your phone's recording position to landscape.

Comment: This works. Note to all: record your videos in landscape. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In case someone still has this problem, I found a way to avoid the distortion on videos caused by Instagram. Instead of opening the instagram app and selecting your video in the app, go to your phone gallery and click on the "Share" button, share to instagram and the distortion goes away! Worked this way for me!

PS: Android user... might work for Iphones as well!

Comment: Just to clarify your last statement, you don't know if this works on the iPhone because you're an Android user?